# AWS EC2 windows - secure encryption at rest with password at boot

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, bitlocker, amazon-ec2

I'm looking for a way to use encryption at rest at aws for windows instances, but I want the instance to be protected from a hacked admin account (although unlikely due to 2fa) or aws itself (yes, also unlikely).

That means I want to somehow actively enter a password / upload a decryption key each time a volume needs to be accessed, like at boot.

Now bitlocker doesn't really work since I don't have a way to enter the pw at boot and the built in volume encryption stores the keys at AWS.

Has anyone solved this somehow?

Comment: Some months ago I had read an (offline) article about a project aiming in encrypted server storage. The approach was to build a minimal pre-boot OS that provides SSH access so that the admin can connect and enter the encryption password to continue the boot process. The minimal boot OS as well as the main OS was Linux based. Not sure if it would be possible to implement something similar with Windows as main OS.

Comment: Hi, that's a good solution for Linux with a minimal dropbear in the initramfs. But no clue how to get something like that in Windows...